# The system cannot find the path specified.Web logic

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I did configure Weblogic Server in eclipse, all good, you can find below a screenshot of the config :

[image: weblogic config]

But when I try to launch server on servers view, I get the following error :

[image: error]

On the console I get :

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

What could be the problem?

I can give further details if needed

Comment: Does the log mention which path it's not able find?

Comment: it doesn't, I dont know what was the problem, but when I did it on a new folder it did solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue. It was due to the folder renaming.

There are many hardcoding done in the WL config files leading to these kind of issues. Ex: setdomainenv.cmd, startweblogic.cmd and many more....

So we should not rename any directories of Weblogic after installation.